# E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "NOT": syntax error

Tags: android

I couldn't see where I made a mistake

ı wont fint it

```
 try{
            SQLiteDatabase mydatabes=this.openOrCreateDatabase("siirler",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
            mydatabes.execSQL("CREATE TABLE İF NOT EXİSTS siirler(isim VARCHAR,numara INT(2))");
            mydatabes.execSQL("INSERT INTO siirler(isim,numara) VALUES('merhaba',12)");
            mydatabes.execSQL("INSERT INTO siirler(isim,numara) VALUES('dünya',13) ");
            Cursor cursor = mydatabes.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM siirler",null);
            int isimindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("isim");
            int numaraindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("numara");
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor!=null){
                System.out.println("isminiz"+cursor.getString(isimindex));
                System.out.println("yaşınız"+cursor.getInt(numaraindex));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }





        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: The i in exists!

Comment: Character "İ" in "IF" and "EXISTS". It should be usual latin "I" not "İ".

Answer (score 0):

The dotted `İ` (`C4B0`) in `İF` and `EXİSTS` is illegal - just replace that with a non-accented `I` (`49`).